# Adding delay to RecyclerView items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a simple RecyclerView.ViewHolder class, which makes the new items 'scale-in' when data is binded to the view. The animation looks good when using the LinearLayoutManager, but when used the GridLayoutManager, all items in the row 'scale in' at the same time.

My goal is to make the items 'scale in' one after another. I'm not sure how to accomplish this and how to add this 'delay' to each item.

One way I could think of is keep track of current position and add different offsetDelay for each animation (if 1st item in a row 500ms, if 2nd item in a row do 1000ms, etc..), but this method gave me weird results:

It works fine for a single row, but while I scroll down, the next row is already starting to scale in, before the last item on previous row has stopped scaling in:

[image]

Is there a better way to do this? Thanks!

My ViewHolder class where I apply the animation:

```
public class ItemHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
   private TextView txtTitle;
   private View     viewItem;

    public ItemHolder( @NonNull View viewItem )
    {
        super( viewItem );

        this.viewItem = viewItem;
        this.txtTitle = itemView.findViewById( R.id.txtTitle );
    }

    public void bindData( final Item item )
    {
        this.txtTitle.setText( item.getTitle() );

        this.animationScaleIn( this.viewItem );
    }

    private void animationScaleIn( View view )
    {
        ScaleAnimation animationScaleIn = new ScaleAnimation( 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f );

        if( this.position % 2f == 0 )
        {
            animationScaleIn.setDuration( 800 );
        }
        else
        {
            animationScaleIn.setDuration( 800 * 2 );
        }

        view.startAnimation( animationScaleIn );
    }
}
```

And here is the ItemAdapter:

```
public class ItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter
{
    private List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();

    public ItemAdapter( final List<Item> items )
    {
        if( items != null )
            this.items = items;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder( @NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int position )
    {
        final View view = LayoutInflater.from( viewGroup.getContext() ).inflate( position, viewGroup, false );
        return new ItemHolder( view );
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder( @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position )
    {
        ((ItemHolder)viewHolder).bindData( this.items.get( position ) );
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType( final int position )
    {
        return R.layout.item;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount()
    {
        return this.items.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: `keep track of current position and add different offsetDelay`, I think you should try it first. If it working well with no problem, may be you don't need another solution.

Comment: I tried, but it gives weird results, I can accomplish the result for the desired row, but the next row is already starting to scale in, before the last item on previous row has stopped scaling in.